# Java file line processing (basics)

Tags: java, file, io, line

I'm having a hard time learning file line processing. I understand how to read through lines of a file with a while loop and .hasNextLine, and I'm even able to print the entire line if it contains the value I'm searching for. I just don't understand how to get individual values (string, int, double) in a specific line of a text file and sort through them then print out the ones I want in a specific order. My professor kinda just sped through this chapter in our textbook and we have a test coming up, any help in figuring this out would be much appreciated (even open to video lecture/tutorial links)

I'll throw together a practice problem below to give and example of what I mean.

**A text file lists score of students on last 3 tests such as:**

```
Nick 85 90 76 Hannah 86 91 66 Joe
           22 35 100
   Zak 100
 40 80
```

and now, say I want to output the top 2 scores for each kid with their names in alphabetical order. How do I do this? The test I'm taking later this week won't allow arrays or any fancy utilities, we will be expected to use only scanner and loops really.

**expected output:**

```
Hannah: 91, 86
Nick: 90, 85
Joe: 100, 35
Zak: 100, 80
```

**how I'm approaching a problem like this right now:**

```
    Scanner exampleFile = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    String name;

    while(exampleFile.hasNextLine()){
        name = exampleFile.nextLine();
        Scanner linescan = new Scanner(name);
        if(linescan.hasNext()){
            int a = linescan.nextInt();
            int b = linescan.nextInt();
            int c = linescan.nextInt();
            int a1 = Math.max(a, b);
            int a2 = Math.max(a, c);

            System.out.println(linescan.next() + ": " + Math.max(a1, a2) + ", " + "middle value idk how to get");
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, or if I'm missing something incredibly obvious that will shine a light on everything and make me a file line processing god. All community wisdom appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the text input is going to be somewhat randomly formatted in terms of what data is on what line, and how many spaces are between each of them.  Is this accurate?

Comment: Yeah, It's randomly formatted. Single space between each data value, then random spacing after line breaks. I kinda just made it up off the top of my head based on what we've done in class. Is it not possible to get the desired output when the data is all over the place like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The test I'm taking later this week won't allow arrays or any fancy utilities, we will be expected to use only scanner and loops really. "

Sorting without data structures is counterproductive, but I digress.

In this situation I think the only way to sort the data would be: to read in the data one line at a time, trim the line, and append it to a `String` with a trailing space. Then you're going to have to come up with some algorithm that crawls said `String` and compares and swaps it's `sub-strings` until it's sorted. Which, from experience, is not the most enjoyable activity.

Here is a working example I just typed up. It uses one `Scanner` for file input, and `String`s. `String`s are not arrays, so that's good. I tried to explain things through comments in the code, but if you need a better explanation just let me know in this answer's comments.

**Note:** this example just sorts the input, it does not find the highest 2 grades, but that should be easy once the input has been sorted. Just pass the sorted `String` through a `Scanner`, parse some data, and voilà.

---

**Driver.java:**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = null;
        String inputStr = "";

        try {
            // open the file "xin.txt" to retrieve input
            in = new Scanner(new File("xin.txt"));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // read the data into a one line string
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            inputStr += in.nextLine().trim() + " ";
        }
        System.out.println("[ORIGINAL]\n" + inputStr + "\n");

        System.out.println("[Start Sorting]");
        inputStr = sortString(inputStr);
        System.out.println("[Done Sorting]\n");

        System.out.println("[Sorted String]\n" + inputStr);
    }

    private static String sortString(String orig) {
        String one = "";
        String two = "";
        int oneStart = 0; // starting index of string to compare with
        int twoStart = 0; // starting index of string to compare against
        int oneStop = 0; // ending index of string to compare with
        int twoStop = 0; // ending index of string to compare against
        int oneTot = 0; // length of string one plus the grades
        int twoTot = 0; // length of string two plus the grades

        int cp = 0; // current position (index)

        boolean onOne = false; // current position is on one
        boolean onTwo = false; // current position is on two
        boolean passOne = false; // passed string one
        boolean passTwo = false; // passed string two


        boolean notDone = true; // control boolean

        while(notDone) {
            if(cp >= orig.length() || isAtoZ(orig.charAt(cp))) {
                if(!onOne && !passOne) {
                    oneStart = cp;
                    onOne = true;
                } else if(passOne && (!onTwo && !passTwo)) {
                    twoStart = cp;
                    onTwo = true;

                    // total length of the first string is the current position
                    // minus the start of the first string
                    oneTot = cp - oneStart;
                } else if(passTwo) {
                    // total length of the second string is the current position
                    // minus the start of the second string
                    twoTot = cp - twoStart;

                    one = orig.substring(oneStart, oneStop);
                    two = orig.substring(twoStart, twoStop);

                    // output the results of the comparing
                    System.out.println(orig);
                    System.out.println("Comparing: " + one + " to " + two);
                    System.out.println("Result: " + one.compareTo(two) + "\n");



                    // if the first string is alphabetically larger, then swap
                    // and restart sort,else continue to the next comparison
                    if(one.compareTo(two) > 0) {
                        orig = rangeSwap(oneStart, oneStart + oneTot,
                        twoStart, twoStart + twoTot, orig);
                        onOne = false;
                        onTwo = false;
                        passOne = false;
                        passTwo = false;

                        cp = -1;
                    } else {
                        onOne = false;
                        onTwo = false;
                        passOne = false;
                        passTwo = false;

                        cp = twoStart - 1;
                    }

                }
            } else {
                if(onOne && !passOne) {
                    oneStop = cp;
                    passOne = true;
                    onOne = false;
                } else if(onTwo && !passTwo) {
                    twoStop = cp;
                    passTwo = true;
                    onTwo = false;
                }
            }

            // increment the current position by one
            cp = cp + 1;

            // the last string has no string to compare to so
            // set the control boolean
            if(cp >= (orig.length()-1) && (!passTwo)) {
                notDone = false;
            }
        }

        // return the sorted string
        return orig;
    }

    private static String rangeSwap(int ob, int oe, int tb, int te, String s) {
        String start = "";
        String x = "";
        String middle = "";
        String y = "";
        String end = "";

        start = s.substring(0, ob);
        x = s.substring(ob, oe);
        middle = s.substring(oe, tb);
        y = s.substring(tb, te);
        end = s.substring(te);

        return start + y + middle + x + end;
    }

    private static boolean isAtoZ(char what) {
        // ASCII character codes: A to Z = 65 to 90
        //                        a to z = 97 to 122
        return (((int)what >= 65 && (int)what <= 90) ||
        ((int)what >= 97 && (int)what <= 122 ));
    }

}
```

**xin.txt:**

```
Nick 85 90 76 Hannah 86 91 66 Joe
           22 35 100
   Zak 100
 40 80
```

**Output:**

```
[Original]
Nick 85 90 76 Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Zak 100 40 80 

[Start Sorting]
Nick 85 90 76 Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Nick to Hannah
Result: 6

Hannah 86 91 66 Nick 85 90 76 Joe 22 35 100 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Hannah to Nick
Result: -6

Hannah 86 91 66 Nick 85 90 76 Joe 22 35 100 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Nick to Joe
Result: 4

Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Nick 85 90 76 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Hannah to Joe
Result: -2

Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Nick 85 90 76 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Joe to Nick
Result: -4

Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Nick 85 90 76 Zak 100 40 80 
Comparing: Nick to Zak
Result: -12

[Done Sorting]

[Sorted String]
Hannah 86 91 66 Joe 22 35 100 Nick 85 90 76 Zak 100 40 80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it the following way. It parses through the file correctly & is able to print the desired output (unsorted):

```
    Scanner exampleFile = new Scanner(new File("file"));
    while (exampleFile.hasNext()) {
        String name = exampleFile.next();
        int a = exampleFile.nextInt();
        int b = exampleFile.nextInt();
        int c = exampleFile.nextInt();
        int max = Math.max(a, b);
        max = Math.max(max, c);
        int min = Math.min(a, b);
        min = Math.min(min, c);
        System.out.println(name + ": " + max + ", " + (a > min && a < max ? a : (b > min && b < max ? b : c)));
    }
    exampleFile.close();
```

If you want to sort, then you'll have to use more than a while loop. Firstly read & store into arrays, then apply any sorting algorithm of choice & then print. Now that you can read the data correctly, you should be able to proceed.

Comment: Since he said that he won't be allowed to use arrays, he'll have to do the 'sorting' it the hard way, with nested if statements.

Comment: @soong Oops. Forgot that part. I guess Jonny's answer will do now.